# extract an array from another array at compile time using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, c++14

Not sure if it's possible for more later version of c++. (I can't figure out using traditional c++ to achieve the following behaviofgr.)

For example,

If I have an array defined like this:

In the header file

```
struct Def {
  static const int N = 5;
  static const double data[N];
};
```

In its cpp

```
const double Def::data[Def::N] = {0,1,2,3,4};
```

Is it possible to have a template `get_subarray` such that

`get_subarray<Def,2,0>::data` will be an array of content `{0,2,4}`

`get_subarray<Def,2,1>::data` will be an array of content `{1,3}`

where

```
template<typename T, int M, int m>
struct get_phase {
    // some code for the array variable data which will 
    // extract element from T::data for every M sample offset by index m
};
```

Comment: You could try using [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) into a second array of the correct size.

Comment: @ElizabethMyers Doesn't happen at compile-time though.

Comment: C++14 makes this easier than C++11

Comment: @Yakk will be really useful to see how both solutions (C++11 vs C++14) to tackle the same problem.

Comment: @carson except the c++11 version is painful to write.  So I would rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the skypjack's solution but it doesn't extract the requested values.  skypjack's version has two parameters, "begin" and "end".  The OP requested "stride" or "frequency" and "begin".

I've modified it to match the OP's requested "frequency" and "start" arguments, giving the template non-type parameters more self-explaining names, and rewriting a couple of index calculations:

```
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>
#include<array>

template <std::size_t Freq, std::size_t Start, typename T, std::size_t Dim,
          std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(I)>
extractHelper (const std::array<T, Dim> & arr,
               std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>)
 { return { { std::get<Freq*I+Start>(arr)... } }; }

template <std::size_t Freq, std::size_t Start, typename T, std::size_t Dim>
constexpr auto extractSamples (const std::array<T, Dim> & arr)
 { return extractHelper<Freq, Start>
      (arr, std::make_index_sequence<(Dim+Freq-1-Start)/Freq>()); }
```

Here is some test code:

```
int main()
 {
   constexpr std::array<int, 8> a1 = { { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 } };

   constexpr auto e1 = extractSamples<2, 0>(a1);
   constexpr auto e2 = extractSamples<2, 1>(a1);
   constexpr auto e3 = extractSamples<3, 0>(a1);
   constexpr auto e4 = extractSamples<3, 1>(a1);
   constexpr auto e5 = extractSamples<3, 2>(a1);

   std::cout << "samples<2, 0>: ";

   for ( auto const & i : e1 )
      std::cout << ' ' << i;

   std::cout << "\nsamples<2, 1>: ";

   for ( auto const & i : e2 )
      std::cout << ' ' << i;

   std::cout << "\nsamples<3, 0>: ";

   for ( auto const & i : e3 )
      std::cout << ' ' << i;

   std::cout << "\nsamples<3, 1>: ";

   for ( auto const & i : e4 )
      std::cout << ' ' << i;

   std::cout << "\nsamples<3, 2>: ";

   for ( auto const & i : e5 )
      std::cout << ' ' << i;

   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

The output is:

```
samples<2, 0>:  0 2 4 6
samples<2, 1>:  1 3 5 7
samples<3, 0>:  0 3 6
samples<3, 1>:  1 4 7
samples<3, 2>:  2 5
```

which matches the OP's requests

Comment: I didn't want to insult you. If you got it as an intention to offend, I apologize.

Comment: @skypjack - OK; maybe I'm to much touchy.

Comment: No problem. Deleted the comment. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't want to insult you.

Comment: @skypjack - No problem: the misunderstanding was I my failure. I see that you've got the point (from the Yakk's comment) about the difference between your solution and the OP question so I've deleted my comment to.

Comment: @Yakk - thanks for the editing: write in English is very difficult for me.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, the OP is interested also in C++14 based solutions.
Here is one of them:

```
#include<functional>
#include<cstddef>
#include<utility>
#include<array>

template<std::size_t O, typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(I)>
f(const std::array<T, N> &arr, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return { std::get<I+O>(arr)... };
}

template<std::size_t B, std::size_t E, typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto f(const std::array<T, N> &arr) {
    return f<B>(arr, std::make_index_sequence<E-B>());
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::array<int, 3> a1 = { 0, 1, 2 };
    constexpr auto a2 = f<1, 2>(a1);
    static_assert(a1[1] == a2[0], "!");
}
```

In this case, `a2` is equal to `{ 1 }`.
It's worth it checking `B` and `E` so as to verify that `E` is greater than `B`, but the example should give an idea of what's the way to do it.

To port it to C++11:

- Do not use `auto` as return type, but explicitly specify `std::array` (easy)
- Search on the web one of the available C++11 implementations of `integer_sequence` and `make_index_sequence` and use it

If it's fine to be explicit about the indexes and not use a range, here is a naïve snippet that should work in C++11:

```
#include<cstddef>
#include<utility>
#include<array>

template<std::size_t... I, typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(I)>
f(const std::array<T, N> &arr) {
    return { std::get<I>(arr)... };
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::array<int, 3> a1 = { 0, 1, 2 };
    constexpr auto a2 = f<1>(a1);
    static_assert(a1[1] == a2[0], "!");
}
```

As in the previous example, `a2` is `{ 1 }`.

Comment: The OP's `get_subarray<Def,2,1>` is `stride` `start`, not `begin` `end` as you wrote.

Comment: @Yakk The C++11 solution works as expected indeed. :-) ... That said, easy to update to do that. I'll have a try in the evening, now I'm at work. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in C++11 without additives. As usual,
compiletime recursion makes do for the lack of C++14's `std::index_sequence`
- in this case by recursively assembling the list of indices that
select the desired sample of the data array.

Given some:

```
constexpr std::array<T,N> data{{...}};
```

initialized `...` with the `T`s of your choice, then:

```
constexpr auto sample = get_sample<Stride,Offset>(data);
```

will define `sample` as a compiletime

```
std::array<T,M>
```

populated with the `M` elements of `data` obtained by selecting the element
at offset `Offset` from the start of successive `Stride`-sized intervals of
`data`.

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr std::size_t 
sample_size(std::size_t size, std::size_t stride, std::size_t off)
{
    return stride == 0 ? 0 : ((size - off) / stride) + 
        (off + (((size - off) / stride) * stride) < size); 
}

template<
    std::size_t Stride = 1, std::size_t Off = 0, 
    typename T, std::size_t Size, std::size_t ...Is
>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<
    sizeof ...(Is) == sample_size(Size,Stride,Off),
    std::array<T, sample_size(Size,Stride,Off)>
>::type
get_sample(std::array<T,Size> const & data)
{
    return std::array<T,sample_size(Size,Stride,Off)>{{data[Is]... }};
}

template<
    std::size_t Stride = 1, std::size_t Off = 0, 
    typename T, std::size_t Size, std::size_t ...Is
>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<
    sizeof ...(Is) != sample_size(Size,Stride,Off),
    std::array<T, sample_size(Size,Stride,Off)>
>::type
get_sample(std::array<T,Size> const & data)
{
    return 
        get_sample<Stride,Off,T,Size,Is...,(sizeof...(Is) * Stride) + Off>
            (data);
}
```

By default `Stride` is `1` and `Off` is `0`. The helper function `sample_size`
embeds the convention that if `Stride` is 0 you get an empty sample.

For an illustrative program, you can append:

```
constexpr std::array<int,5> data1{{0,1,2,3,4}};
constexpr auto sample1 = get_sample(data1);
constexpr auto sample2 = get_sample<2>(data1);
constexpr auto sample3 = get_sample<2,1>(data1);
constexpr auto sample4 = get_sample<6>(data1);
constexpr auto sample5 = get_sample<6,5>(data1);
static_assert(sample5.size() == 0,"");
constexpr std::array<float,6> data2{{1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6}};
constexpr auto sample6 = get_sample<2>(data2);
constexpr auto sample7 = get_sample<2,3>(data2);
constexpr auto sample8 = get_sample<3,2>(data2);
constexpr std::array<int,0> data3{};
constexpr auto sample9 = get_sample<0>(data3);
static_assert(sample9.size() == 0,"");
constexpr auto sample10 = get_sample<2>(data3);
static_assert(sample10.size() == 0,"");

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "get_sample<> of {0,1,2,3,4}\n";
    for (auto const & e : sample1) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "get_sample<2> of {0,1,2,3,4}\n";
    for (auto const & e : sample2) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "get_sample<2,1> of {0,1,2,3,4}\n";
    for (auto const & e : sample3) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "get_sample<6> of {0,1,2,3,4}\n";
    for (auto const & e : sample4) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "get_sample<2> of {{1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6}}\n";
    for (auto const & e : sample6) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "get_sample<2,3> of {{1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6}}\n";
    for (auto const & e : sample7) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "get_sample<3,2> of {{1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6}}\n";
    for (auto const & e : sample8) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

which reports:

```
get_sample<> of {0,1,2,3,4}
0 1 2 3 4 
get_sample<2> of {0,1,2,3,4}
0 2 4 
get_sample<2,1> of {0,1,2,3,4}
1 3 
get_sample<6> of {0,1,2,3,4}
0 
get_sample<2> of {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6}
1.1 3.3 5.5 
get_sample<2,3> of {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6}
4.4 6.6 
get_sample<3,2> of {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6}
3.3 6.6
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a88493bc678c2ec8)

If you want to apply this to your class `Def`, you would redefine it in an amenable
way like:

```
struct Def {
  static constexpr int N = 5;
  static constexpr std::array<double,N> data{{0,1,2,3,4}};
};
```

and get your compiletime sample like:

```
constexpr auto s = get_sample<2,1>(Def::data);
```

(g++ 6.1/clang++ 3.8, -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)